# How to work out the number of ways a user can be asked to enter 3 characters from a memorable word.

Tags: permutations

A bank when you sign in asks for a Userid and a Password and when accepted asks for 3 characters from a previously registered memorable word. The numbers of the characters are always in ascending order. Example 1,4,7 or 5,6,7 but never 1,7,4 or 5,7,6.
 Research has found the normal formula P(N,k) = N!/(N-k)! but this does not cater for the ordering of the resulting sequence of numbers.
 My question is how can this catered for?
 I have iterated the list for 3 from 8, 3 from 9, 3 from 10 and 3 from 11 and get the answers 56, 84, 120, 162.

Comment: You want combinations, not permutations.  Look for $C(n,k)$ instead of $P(n,k)$.

Comment: You should specify that the numbers must be distinct (the values you give make it clear that you are requiring that).

Comment: You just want a selection of $3$ characters in which there is only one arrangement that's ascending, But $P(N, k)$ also arranges characters

Comment: As an aside, $\binom{8}{3}=56,\binom{9}{3}=84,\binom{10}{3}=120,\binom{11}{3}=16\color{red}{5}$ (*not 162*).  See more uses of the [binomial coefficient at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for combinations instead of permutations.
$$ C(n,k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks that explains I could not get the formula to work . My error.